# How to convert wordpress post into image and make it downloadable?

Tags: php, wordpress, html2canvas

I had created one wordpress site. I want to make all post downloadable by converting it to image.

I tried using [canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) but didn't succeed.

Can any one suggest me better working way on wordpress which lets me convert my post to image and make it downloadable?

I want to make post covered with specific div so that i can define size of content to be downloaded.

Like this [HTML2CANVAS](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) but I am unable to do.

*PS-I have very small size of content in every post*

Comment: If you are happy to have the image the same as it is rendered in a browser (namely webkit).  You could try: http://phantomjs.org/.

Comment: Perhaps convert words to images: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php , or find a good library.

Comment: Try `webkit2png -o image http://www.google.com`

Comment: I would prefer free service.More over I didn't want to take screenshot of any url. I want to make my own content as image

Answer (score 1):

I think your options are

1. Use some third-party service, such as http://web-capture.net/ or https://www.url2png.com . Most of them, especially the ones with API that you can call on-demand, will cost you, but there are free alternatives.
2. If you have access to linux console and some basic knowledge about it, the best approach is to run a real browser (if you're using a headless server, use Xvfb) with your post URL and make a screenshot with ImageMagick. You can crop the image to remove browser header etc. A working-grade explanation here http://www.leonardteo.com/2011/07/taking-server-side-screenshots-of-websites/ .

In both cases PHP will be just the trigger, whether it will call third-party API or your local shell script.

I'd also suggest to avoid JPEG format as it doesn't really play well with text. Use PNG instead.

Comment: i am fine with any format. I just want to get it downloadable as image

Answer (score 0):

You may try rendering the text with imagettftext() as @Progrock suggested, but this will be a huge pain, because you obviously have text with more than one line. First you need to determine the width of your image, then use imagettfbbox() to roughly estimate how many characters you can fit into one line, split your text into chunks of that size and write then one by one, adding the Y coordinate. Bonus points if you need paragraphs here... Make sure you're using monotype font, because it won't ever work properly with variable-width letters. look through comments here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php.

My advice - stick with the browser :) You can resize the browser window and crop the extra part.